# Не получается правильно передать параметры в highload block

Tags: php, битрикс

Вопрос простой, но у меня затык:
Обращаюсь к этой функции:

```js
<?php
CModule::IncludeModule("highloadblock"); 
CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
CModule::IncludeModule("user");
use Bitrix\Highloadblock as HL; 
use Bitrix\Main\Entity; 

class class2 {
public function inHL($ID, $filter) {
        $hlblock = HL\HighloadBlockTable::getById($ID)->fetch(); 
        $entity = HL\HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity($hlblock); 
        $entity_data_class = $entity->getDataClass(); 
        $rsData = $entity_data_class::getList(array(
           'select' => array('*'),
           'filter' => $filter
        ));
        $request = [];

        while($el = $rsData->fetch()){
            array_push($request, $el);
        }

        return $request;
    }
}
```

Обращаюсь к ней с тестовой страницы:

```js
$getHL = new class2;
$variable = $getHL->inHL(14, array('?UF_FIRSTNAME'=>'Ольга'));
```

Пытаюсь таким образом передать параметры: 14 хайлоад блока и значения фильтра по имени. Не получается это правильно передать параметры фильтра `array('?UF_FIRSTNAME'=>'Ольга')` Как это правильно сделать??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ищется подстрока, то вместо "?" надо использовать "%"

```
array('%UF_FIRSTNAME'=>'Ольга')
```

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5753

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!!